# Failed when present UIviewcontroller

Tags: uiviewcontroller

I have 2 viewcontrollers: mainVC & listVC. 
I tapped customized button on mainVC to present listVC, then tapped button on listVC to go back to mainVC. until now there is no any failure. But when I tap customized button to go to listVC again, program failed.

error:
**NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Application tried to present modal view controller on itself. Presenting controller is 
 Voice_of_Animals.ListVC: 0x7feeee513210>**

```
class ViewController: UIViewController
```

{

```
var cb = CirButton(Circolor: UIColor.cyan, Rsize: 100, PositionX: 100, PositionY: 100)
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    mainVC = self
    self.view.addSubview(cb)
    listVC.transitioningDelegate = listVC as UIViewControllerTransitioningDelegate

}

func showNextPage() {
self.present(listVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
}

@IBAction func show(_ sender: UIButton) {
self.present(listVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
@IBAction func Touch(_ sender: CButton) {
    sender.RunAnimation()
}
override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
}
```

}

```
 class ListVC: ViewController{
var transition = FadeAnimator()
var btn1 = CirButton(Circolor: UIColor.cyan, Rsize: 100, PositionX: 100, PositionY: 100)
@IBOutlet weak var myList: ListView!
@IBAction func Push(_ sender: UIButton) {
}

@IBAction func edgeSlide(_ sender: UIScreenEdgePanGestureRecognizer) {
  mainVC.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.view.addSubview(btn1)
}
```

}